# VB.NET dynamic controls deployment

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, controls

Below is a well working VBA code adding controls to whatever object admitting them while drawing the data from a db table. This works so well coz here I have an **.Add** method admitting 2 string variables defining control type and name. Cannot find anything like that on VB.Net. I can only make separate procedures for each control type. This code is not usable because I cannot build a *MSForms.UserForm* in abstracto. It must have a prototype build with form designer, while this on VS does not build *MSForms.UserForms*, but *System.Windows.Forms* only.
Any solution apart from making my own procedure with plenty of Selects, Ifs and similar? This still **worked in VB.6** - there are historical solutions on the WEB and on this platform.

```
Function formFill(obj As Object, strSQL As String) As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, cntr As MSForms.Control, c As String

c = ""
On Error GoTo formFill_err
Set rs = ui_cnt.Execute(strSQL)

Do While Not rs.EOF

    Set cntr = obj.Controls.Add("Forms." + rs("obj_type") + ".1", rs("obj_name"), True)
    cntr.Height = rs("Height")

    If Left(cntr.Name, 3) = "lbl" And cntr.Height > 32 Then cntr.WordWrap = True
    cntr.Left = rs("Left")
    cntr.Top = rs("Top")
    cntr.Width = rs("Width")
    cntr.Caption = str_convert_null(rs("caption"))
    cntr.ControlTipText = str_convert_null(rs("tip"))
    cntr.Font.Size = 8
    cntr.Visible = True
    If Left(cntr.Name, 3) = "txt" Then
        cntr.AutoSize = False
    Else
        cntr.AutoSize = True
    End If

    c = c + rs("obj_type") + ";" + rs("obj_name") + ";"
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set rs = Nothing
formFill = c
Exit Function
formFill_err:
If Err.Number = 438 Then Resume Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample how to create controls in `Windows Form`.

First, declare a container for your control setup. This is a class which replaces your `ADODB.Recordset` object.

```
Public Class MyControl
    Public Property obj_type As String
    Public Property obj_name As String
    Public Property Top As Integer
    Public Property Left As Integer
    Public Property Height As Integer
    Public Property Width As Integer
    Public Property caption As String
    Public Property tip As String
End Class
```

Here's a function which return an array of the class I defined before. I hardcoded the values (2 labels and 1 textbox), but you can also fetch the values from other sources like tables in database. You can replace the content of this function with any database technology for .Net, eg. ADO.Net or Entity Framework (EF).

```
Private Function GetMyControls() As MyControl()

    Return {
        New MyControl With {
            .obj_type = "System.Windows.Forms.Label",
            .obj_name = "lblLabel1",
            .Top = 20,
            .Left = 20,
            .Height = 30,
            .Width = 100,
            .caption = "Label 1 caption",
            .tip = "Label 1 tooltip"
        },
        New MyControl With {
            .obj_type = "System.Windows.Forms.Label",
            .obj_name = "lblLabel2",
            .Top = 60,
            .Left = 20,
            .Height = 100,
            .Width = 100,
            .caption = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            .tip = "Label 2 tooltip"
        },
        New MyControl With {
            .obj_type = "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox",
            .obj_name = "txtTextbox1",
            .Top = 200,
            .Left = 20,
            .Height = 500,
            .Width = 500,
            .caption = "abcdef",
            .tip = "Textbox 1 tooltip"
        }
    }

End Function
```

Then create each control from the setup then add it into the form's control collections.

```
Private Sub BuildMyControls()

    'get controls setup
    Dim myControls = GetMyControls()

    For Each myControl In myControls

        'get control type
        Dim myControlType = GetType(Control).Assembly.GetType(myControl.obj_type)
        'create control
        Dim cntr As Control = Activator.CreateInstance(myControlType, True)
        'setting properties
        With cntr
            .Name = myControl.obj_name
            .Top = myControl.Top
            .Left = myControl.Left
            .Height = myControl.Height
            .Width = myControl.Width
            .Text = myControl.caption
            .Font = New Font(.Font.Name, 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular)
        End With

        'add an event handler (optional), uncomment the if statement if you want to do it for labels only
        'If myControl.obj_type = "System.Windows.Forms.Label" Then
        AddHandler cntr.Click, AddressOf MyControl_Click
        'End If

        'add new control into form's control collection
        Me.Controls.Add(cntr)
    Next

End Sub
```

Put the control creating method in the form's load event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BuildMyControls()
End Sub
```

Last is optional, I add an event handler for the control click event. This method is called in the control creating method above.

```
Private Sub MyControl_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim cntr = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    'old version (formatted string)
    'Dim message = String.Format("You clicked a {0} named {1}", cntr.GetType, cntr.Name)
    'new version (interpolated string)
    Dim message = $"You clicked a {cntr.GetType} named {cntr.Name}"
    MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub
```

Full code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        BuildMyControls()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyControl_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim cntr = DirectCast(sender, Control)
        'old version (formatted string)
        'Dim message = String.Format("You clicked a {0} named {1}", cntr.GetType, cntr.Name)
        'new version (interpolated string)
        Dim message = $"You clicked a {cntr.GetType} named {cntr.Name}"
        MessageBox.Show(message)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BuildMyControls()

        'get controls setup
        Dim myControls = GetMyControls()

        For Each myControl In myControls

            'get control type
            Dim myControlType = GetType(Control).Assembly.GetType(myControl.obj_type)
            'create control
            Dim cntr As Control = Activator.CreateInstance(myControlType, True)
            'setting properties
            With cntr
                .Name = myControl.obj_name
                .Top = myControl.Top
                .Left = myControl.Left
                .Height = myControl.Height
                .Width = myControl.Width
                .Text = myControl.caption
                .Font = New Font(.Font.Name, 8.0F, FontStyle.Regular)
            End With

            'add an event handler (optional), uncomment the if statement if you want to do it for labels only
            'If myControl.obj_type = "System.Windows.Forms.Label" Then
            AddHandler cntr.Click, AddressOf MyControl_Click
            'End If

            'add new control into form's control collection
            Me.Controls.Add(cntr)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Function GetMyControls() As MyControl()

        Return {
            New MyControl With {
                .obj_type = "System.Windows.Forms.Label",
                .obj_name = "lblLabel1",
                .Top = 20,
                .Left = 20,
                .Height = 30,
                .Width = 100,
                .caption = "Label 1 caption",
                .tip = "Label 1 tooltip"
            },
            New MyControl With {
                .obj_type = "System.Windows.Forms.Label",
                .obj_name = "lblLabel2",
                .Top = 60,
                .Left = 20,
                .Height = 100,
                .Width = 100,
                .caption = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                .tip = "Label 2 tooltip"
            },
            New MyControl With {
                .obj_type = "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox",
                .obj_name = "txtTextbox1",
                .Top = 200,
                .Left = 20,
                .Height = 500,
                .Width = 500,
                .caption = "abcdef",
                .tip = "Textbox 1 tooltip"
            }
        }

    End Function

End Class

Public Class MyControl
    Public Property obj_type As String
    Public Property obj_name As String
    Public Property Top As Integer
    Public Property Left As Integer
    Public Property Height As Integer
    Public Property Width As Integer
    Public Property caption As String
    Public Property tip As String
End Class
```

I don't write code for the wordwrap, autosize and tooltip.